# Hyperledger Composer Vehicle Lifecycle Network

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

When I try to create a Business (ScrapMerchant, Regulator, Manufacturer, Company & AuctionHouse) Participant I get the following error.

**Error: No concrete extending type for composer.business.Manager**

In any real case scenario, a business is always managed by an Employee of that business. How can I achieve this in Hyperledger Composer.

Ex: How can I add *John* as an admin of a *Regulator* or a *Manufacturer*, who can invoke transaction on behalf of a *Regulator/Manufacturer* ?

Comment: Your question doesn't describe the scenario adequately. There is an issue #2591 https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues/2591  which describes your issue. Its not clear whether you're using this sample as the basis for your own network? . In that context, is John in Manufacturer org? Would he be the invoker of trxns as one identity, or is a separate audit trail ("ids to submit trxns on behalf of.." ) required,  to show separate invocations on behalf of participants from those types?

Comment: Suppose John is a Manager at Toyota(Manufacturer) . How can he invoke the updateOrderStatus transaction on behalf of Toyota.

Comment: My use case is based on sample vehicle lifecycle network of Hyperledger Composer

Comment: please edit your comment to use link https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/managing/participantsandidentities (as 0.16 is for an older version of Composer). When done, I will remove this comment !

Comment: Things seems to be clearer after reading this https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/managing/participantsandidentities thanks @PaulO'Mahony

Comment: hi @PaulO'Mahony In  the sample vehicle lifecycle network, which rest-server will the private owner interact with? Suppose in a case where the client application doesn't trust the rest server with their private key. What are the other options ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to review https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/managing/participantsandidentities for a clearer understanding of using participants and identities in a Composer business network, deployed to a Fabric blockchain network.

Comment: hi @PaulO'Mahony In  the sample vehicle lifecycle network, which rest-server will the private owner interact with? Suppose in a case where the client application doesn't trust the rest server with their private key. What are the other options ? Thanks.